# Word for 'somebody is deeply satisfied after completing a job perfectly'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single adjective for a person who experiences a deep satisfaction on completing a job perfectly and completely. Also, the person might possibly be passionate about the job in question.

Comment: Does the person also take satisfaction in writing his own resume and cover letters? Might he be passionate about that job as well? Or is he the kind of person who gets deep satisfaction from the *credit* for completing a job he successfully fobbed off on someone else without demonstrating any effort of his own?

Comment: @DanBron: No, he/she is just the kind of person who gets personal satisfaction from doing a good job. For instance, a cobbler who might get satisfaction on making a really good pair of shoes (not satisfaction because of the money he would get).

Comment: Could you provide a sentence where this word would fit? And could you explain why the expression *satisfied* does not fulfil your needs. *cough*, *cough*

Comment: Is this not just a *motivated* person?

Answer (score -2):

An adjective... for a person...  **"gratified"**

> - gratify - to reward, satisfy, or please. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gratify)

- Having worked hard for so many years, he felt deeply gratified when he mapped the whole viral DNA.